# Jshell in intellij doesn't allow generic types

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jshell, java-14

I just started using jshell in intellij idea community version. When I write the below code in jshell, it works.

```
List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c");
System.out.println(list);
```

However the same code doesn't work in intellij. It says "Expression expected". It executes fine but shows that there is error with `List<String>`. The problem is "auto-complete" doesn't work. To workaround this issue, we can use raw type but I want a generic one. Is there something that I am missing? How can I write a generic type?

Comment: Aside - There seem to be a decent number of [bugs open on Jshell integration in IJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=jshell)

Comment: Please see the bug already created for the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190187

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not an IntelliJ IDEA expert but I get my way around by writing a anonymous class:

```
new Object() {
    void method() {
        List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}.method();
```